# Как вывести записи на странице wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создана отдельная страница "База знаний", в ней хочу размещать посты:
файл page.php

```
<?php get_header() ?>
<div class="container">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page');
endwhile; ?>
<!-- post navigation -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- no posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Файл content.php

```
<article class="article">
  <h3 class="article__title">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
  <span class="article__date">
    <?php the_date('d.m.Y') ?>
  </span>
  </h3>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', 'class=article__img'); ?>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div>
  <footer class="article__footer">
    <div class="tags">
      <?php the_tags('<span>Теги:</span> '); ?>
    </div>
  </footer>
</article>
```

А выводится на странице "база знаний" вот что:

```
База знаний 02.02.2018
что-то полезное

что-то полезное
```

Т.е требуется чтобы выводились именно список постов с их кратким содержанием, а тут выводятся вместо постов параметры страниц. И как сделать это именно только для одной страницы ("база знаний")?

Answer (score 0):

> Создана отдельная страница "База знаний", в ней хочу размещать посты:

Для этого нужно создавать не страницу, а рубрику.

А может будет лучше - свой тип постов со своими таксономиями.
См https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_post_types#Custom_Post_Types
https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies